# Calling APIM Manager API failing

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to register an event hub logger with an APIM instance and I am getting an error, like the URL does not exist at all (if i try in a browser, the url resolves fine).

I used the same format of message and call for an APIM instance in another environment and it worked fine.

[image: Response I am getting]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are testing in postman as seen in the above image. Also through the browser you mentioned it works fine.
Can you do the following settings on your postman to resolve the issue

1. Go to postman settings.
2. Under General tab disable SSL Certification verification to off state.

Let me know if this helps!! Cheers!

Comment: Hey, SSL  Cert verification is off. However, I created a new tab to query it and copy and pasted what I had in the other. It then went through fine. So the issue was postman in the end with regards to the tab

Answer (score 0):

I created a new tab to query it and copy and pasted what I had from the other. It then went through fine. So the issue was postman in the end with regards to the tab